# MySQL 5.7: Query fica mais rápida com order by

Tags: mysql, sql-select, order-by

Estou fazendo alguns testes no banco de dados MySQL 5.7, e me deparei com uma situação que não consigo entender:

Quando faço a seguinte consulta:

```
select
*
from
    funcionario
where
    (data_admissao between '2020-01-01 23:59:59' and '2022-07-25 23:59:59')
    order by nome;
```

Quando executo sem "order by nome" a consulta executa em 6s, já com o "order by nome" a consulta executa em 86ms.

OBS:

- Não existe índice para a coluna "nome".
- A tabela utiliza Engine = InnoDB
- Executei o EXPLAIN, mas como é uma consulta simples, não trouxe nenhuma informação significativa:

  1   SIMPLE  funcionario     ALL                 117432  0.01    Using where; Using filesort
- Fiz o mesmo teste no banco de dados MySQL 8, e não obteve nenhuma diferença com o "order by nome", utilizando a mesma base de dados, com a mesma estrutura.

Estou tentando entender a situação, pois quero migrar para o MySQL 8, e gostaria de saber se existe alguma configuração ou estrategia que faça o MySQL 5.7 ter uma diferença com o order by.

Comment: Já tentou no MySQL 8 usar o [`OPTIMIZE TABLE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/optimize-table.html) com a tabela `funcionario` e refazer a consulta para ver se há diferença.

Comment: @AugustoVasques a tabela utiliza Engine = InnoDB, desse modo, o comando OPTIMIZE TABLE não funciona.